# Babel: Respect preamble hyphenation breakpoints when insert extra breakpoint in document

Tags: babel, hyphenation

Is it possible to insert extra breakpoints in a word beyond those already defined with `\hyphenation{}` or `\babelhyphenation{}` in the preamble? In the example below, the (lack of) breakpoints defined in the preamble are completely ignored once I add a custom breakpoint using `\babelhyphen{soft}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\textwidth=1pt
\parindent=0pt
\hyphenation{incomprehensibility}%or \babelhyphenation{incomprehensibility}
\begin{document}
  xxx incomprehensibility \\% not hyphenated as per preamble

  xxx i\babelhyphen{soft}ncomprehensibility% not hyphenated as i-ncomprehensibility, but as i-ncom-pre-hens-ib-il-ity
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands like `\babelhyphen{soft}` work by inserting a space of width zero. So effectively they split a word into two words. If you want to control the hypenation of a part you have to set it up in `\hyphenation` too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\textwidth=1pt
\parindent=0pt
\hyphenation{incomprehensibility ncomprehensibility}% both parts \babelhyphenation{incomprehensibility}
\begin{document}
  xxx incomprehensibility \\% not hyphenated as per preamble

  xxx i\babelhyphen{soft}ncomprehensibility% 
\end{document}
```

[image]